# FlashBuilder: how to embed graphics for preloader?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, preloader, swc

I develop a project in FlashBuilder. The graphics and UI elements i create in the Flash IDE and give them Export Classnames. then I put the SWC in the library paths of the FlashBuilder project and create the UI elements by instanciation.

Now I want to add a Preloader for the application. I follow this article, which works:

http://pixelpaton.com/?p=4642

My question is now: I also need some graphics for the preloader. But how do I ensure that the graphics for the preloader will be loaded first, such that the preloader class can start as soon as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler will figure out the dependencies for your preloader class, and load them first.

For example:

```
public function Preloader()
{
    addChild(new UIElementFromFlash());
}
```

Flash Builder will know `UIElementFromFlash` needs to be loaded before `Preloader`.  It will also load `Preloader` before your main class and its dependencies as long as you have the Frame metadata tag from the article.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to make 2 swf files if it's possible. Make a loader.swf which loads your application swf and displays the progress and your loading animation/graphics.
See an example here: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3preloader/

Then you'll have to add URLLoader class and load your application.swf. 
Try looking here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html

Comment: sure i thoght of that - but for my understanding of how the FlashBuilder, metatags and the swf compiler work it would be cool to know how to do it in a single project

Comment: try looking at this post it'll help you with meta tags: http://frankieloscavio.blogspot.com/2007/12/embed-meta-tag-is-flex-only-it-will-not.html

Comment: you can add your graphics or another swf by using Embed tag in flex.

Comment: but how do I control whether it's content is loaded earlier or later than other stuff that got compiled into my target?

Comment: try doing like this:
[Embed(source="applicationSWF")]
private var ApplicationClass:Class;
This will generate a class called ApplicationClass and it's content will be the swf you embed. so the document class will only have a loader. You'll then try to add this class after the load has completed. You won't need to control anything, first the document class dependencies will be loaded, then your applicationSWF. This is the only method I know.

Answer (score 0):

Like Gio suggested, having two SWF files is the best practice.

However, one other solution is to use the `-frame two` argument of the Flex compiler. All your definitions (code and assets) will be added to the second frame of the movie, allowing your main class to listen for the loading progress of the application and display animations.
Be careful to not **reference anything from the main application** in your first frame, to prevent adding more weight to it.

More detail on this technique here:
http://www.andymoore.ca/2009/08/flexsdk-3-3-how-to-make-a-flash-preloader-in-as3/